# LocalStorage getItem() giving null and then true in Material App on app start: Flutter LocalStorage

Tags: android, flutter, authentication, local-storage, storage

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final LocalStorage status = new LocalStorage('status');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(' Status: ${status.getItem('status')}'); //here I get null and then true after some time
    
    return MaterialApp(
        title: ‘Sample App’,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: status.getItem('status') == 'true'
            ? Home()
            : RegisterDetails(),
```

I am storing the status using setItem(), to true if the user logs in successfully. But the next I open my app, I get redirected again to the register page, not the home screen. I am getting null in status and after some time I get true which I want. Please help!

Comment: Have you carefully watched the example here https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage/example? The storage need to be ready so you need an async mechanism to wait before it can return the values. In the example it uses a `FutureBuilder` waiting for `storage.ready` at first

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `LocalStorage` is [ready](https://pub.dev/documentation/localstorage/latest/localstorage/LocalStorage/ready.html) for operations.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: FutureBuilder(
      future: status.ready,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return status.getItem('status') == 'true'
              ? Home()
              : RegisterDetails();
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: This is not working. Same issue again. Values are stored properly as I am getting it as true but not at the time I want it. By the time I get the value, the screen is opened. Also- the build() is getting called twice . The first time I get null and the second time I get true.

Comment: status.ready is always false